# This footer stays put in Chrome, how can I make it stay the same in Firefox

Tags: css, footer

This footer stays put in Chrome, how can I rewrite the HTML or CSS to make it stay the same in Firefox?

http://goo.gl/rAbH6

Like, when I visit the page in Chrome and then zoom out, the footer stays at the bottom of the screen, but when I visit the same page in Firefox and try zooming out the footer won't stay in the right place.

You'll see what I mean if you try visiting the page.

Anyone knows?

Kind regards

Pongy

Comment: what do you mean by "zooming out"? My first thought was like on a mobile phone, but since mobile phones don't have browser's like Firefox & Chrome I was stumped. I tried viewing the page on Chrome & Firefox(4) and it appears in the same place for both. I tried holding CTRL and scrolling down on the mouse-wheel to get some sort of text-zoom going and it still appears in the same place on both browsers.

Comment: Well, in Firefox and IE the footer goes up if you zoom out enough but in Chrome it stays at the bottom, which is what I'm trying to achieve for all browsers.

Comment: I would experiment. For me, when I zoom out enough in Chrome this happens anyway. Why are you trying to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Because it's a footer and it's supposed to stay down. Because I like it that way. There's no point in questioning the question itself, I would rather have a solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is right here with your code.

```
#footer {
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(images/bottombar.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

As you can see, you've told it to be absolute and relative, so you're duplicating code for no reason and margin-top with 400px; so no matter how much you zoom in or out, you've told it to remain explicitly in that position. Whereas you should have the following code:

```
#footer {
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(images/bottombar.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    top:100%;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

So now we're telling it to go from the top, down to the bottom of the page, with a height of 40px, so we're now displaying it outside of the document itself, so then we margin-top it back in to place, which is the 40px of height we assigned.#

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work at all. See for yourself, the footer almost disappeared - it shrunk in size and stuck to the left side of the screen.

Comment: Yes, that's done what it should've done, with absolute, there are no references to widths and heights, so unless you specify them, they are just inherited, so if we add a display: block; or a width: 100%; that will fix your width issue.

Comment: Ok, applied a width: 100% line resulting in the footer now not sticking to the bottom in neither Chrome or Firefox. I. e. instead of having the footer stick to the bottom in Firefox as it did in Chrome it now won't stick to the bottom in Chrome, just like it didn't in Firefox.

Comment: The final thing to do is on your body tag in CSS, get rid of position: relative and you're all good. :)

Comment: It worked, but now the footer overlaps the text when I zoom in?

Comment: No problem, without making usage of massive code, head on over to the javascript section now and make a post, so when a user scrolls up/down, that bar moves with it, you'll have a nice fluid motion with that.

Comment: There is, you can put everything starting from after <body> but before <footer> into a tag of their own and make a scrollable div within that, so then your content always drops before the footer bar and you've still got a scrolling system, but you'll have to disable scrolling on the <body> tag.